# Can't scroll through picker view

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, pickerview

This is my code for the picker view:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return teams[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return teams.count

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    HomeName.text = teams[row]
}
```

The picker view shows up under the label, but when I try to select an option from the picker view nothing happens. I see the options but can't move them. Help! Thanks!

Comment: must be a view in your view hierarchy in front of your pickerView, debug your view hierarchy and let me know

Comment: how you are showing the picker view?

Comment: Share storyboard snapshot with view hierarchy, you have designed

Comment: Can't get picture up, but it is the button, the label, then the pickerview.

Comment: Ensure that the view has `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `true`.

Comment: I got it working, I think a view was covering it